# VBA powerpoint, run timed task/macro in background across presentation

Tags: vba, timer, background, powerpoint

I am trying to build a presentation with a counter/number in the footer which evolves with time (as a function of some external data set present in an Excel spreadsheet). I developed the VBA code for loading data from the spreadsheet, built a footer in the Slide Master and a macro for updating the counter in it (and even graph some data in the footer), but I am unable to build the mechanism for updating the counter - e.g. every 2 seconds - across the presentation (by that I mean that the update has to happen independently of the active/view slide). I've seen a few threads with similar topics [[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748785/vba-powerpoint-macro-run-in-background), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964813/powerpoint-vba-update-linked-graph-from-excel-at-regular-intervals)], which were not really answered or active, **hence my question:** is there a way to build a *background timer* for launching macros in VBA/Powerpoint?

Thank you and best regards,

Cedric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has an Application.OnTime event to handle this but I can't see one in Powerpoint. Not sure what your setup is but if you have an Excel sheet open as well you could use Application.OnTime from Excel to run the Macro in Powerpoint

Something like

Excel

`Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "my_Procedure"`

`Public Sub my_procedure()
    Dim PPObj As Object
    Set PPObj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
    PPObj.Run "myPPTFile.ppt!MyMacro"
End Sub`

Comment: Thank you! I implement both a solution based on your answer, and the following that I just found \[[ref](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/9f6891f2-d0c4-47a6-b63f-48405aae4022/powerpoint-run-macro-on-timer)\].